# Add namespace only at root node while creating xml in java

Tags: java, xml, dom, namespaces

How can I add namespace only at root node when creating a new XML using DOM Parser in java.

Expected Output is this :

```
<root xmlns = "http://www.mynamespace.com/something/something"> 
       <data1> 
          <parameter> 
                 <name>test string</name> 
                 <value>test string</value> 
             </parameter> 
          <parameter> 
                 <name>test string</name> 
                 <value>test string</value> 
             </parameter> 
      </data1> 
      <data2> 
          <parameter> 
                 <name>test string</name> 
                 <value>test string</value> 
             </parameter> 
          <parameter> 
                 <name>test string</name> 
                 <value>test string</value> 
             </parameter> 
      </data2></root>
```

my code is like this :

```
    Namespace ns = Namespace.getNamespace("http://www.mynamespace.com/something/something");
Element root = new Element("root",ns);  
Document doc = new Document(root);
doc.setRootElement(root);
```

I'm getting out as :

```
<root xmlns="http://www.mynamespace.com/something/something"> 
   <data1 xmlns=""> 
          <parameter> 
                 <name>test string</name> 
                 <value>test string</value> 
             </parameter> 
          <parameter> 
                 <name>test string</name> 
                 <value>test string</value> 
             </parameter> 
      </data1> 
      <data2 xmlns=""> 
          <parameter> 
                 <name>test string</name> 
                 <value>test string</value> 
             </parameter> 
          <parameter> 
                 <name>test string</name> 
                 <value>test string</value> 
             </parameter> 
      </data> </root>
```

That is I don't want **xmlns=""** for `<data1>` and `<data2>`

Thanks

Comment: How do you create the other xml elements?

Comment: I'm creating a new Element (say data) , and after setting the child for this I'm adding this Element to root  like :

doc.getRootElement().addContent(data);

Also I'm using JDOM Parser to create xml File.

Comment: Try to create these element the way you create `root` (`new Element("whatever",ns);`). I guess that the spurious `xmlns` are set since you've set the default namespace for the root element while you create the other nodes without any namespace (thus they reside in a different namespaces conceptually). Without the `xmlns=""` they would belong to `root` namespace. A smart serializer should suppress unnecessary lexicalisations of namespace declarations (so your xml files shouldn't be cluttered with `xmlns` attributes. Anyway, if they are, they can be streamlined by a postprocessor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently was facing the same problem, I am using the XOM parser

```
Element root = new Element("organization", "http://schemas.test");
    Document document = new Document(root); 
    Element element = new Element("Email");
    element.appendChild("test@test.com");
    root.appendChild(element);
    System.out.print(document.toXML());
```

The output is

```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <organization xmlns="http://schemas.test">
    <Email xmlns="">test@test.com</Email>
</organization>
```

Even I wanted the namespace to be present only on the root element organization.
For this apply the same namespace applied to the root element, to the child elements also. So they will then be in the same namespace as the root.

```
Element root = new Element("organization", "http://schemas.test");
        Document document = new Document(root); 
        Element element = new Element("Email","http://schemas.test");
        element.appendChild("test@test.com");
        root.appendChild(element);
System.out.print(document.toXML());
```

This produces the xml as follows with only root element having the namespace-

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <organization xmlns="http://schemas.test">
<Email>test@test.com</Email>
</organization>
```